# How to save failed messages from Amazon SNS into Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I would like to know if it's possible to persist all unacknowledged messages from an SNS topic to an S3 file given a certain time window. These messages don't necessarily need to follow the original order in the S3 file, a timestamp attribute is enough.

Comment: What are "unacknowledged messages"?

Comment: By saying "unacknowledged" I mean "message I didn't consume yet". Once I consume these messages and save to S3 I will "ack" them.

Comment: Messages are not "consumed" from Amazon SNS. Rather, Amazon SNS _sends_ messages to subscribers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is to save all messages published to your SNS topic in an S3 bucket, then you can simply subscribe to your SNS topic the AWS Event Fork Pipeline for Storage & Backup:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-fork-pipeline-as-subscriber.html#sns-fork-event-storage-and-backup-pipeline

** Jan 2021 Update: SNS now supports Kinesis Data Firehose as a native subscription type. https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/01/amazon-sns-adds-support-for-message-archiving-and-analytics-via-kineses-data-firehose-subscriptions/

Answer (score 0):

There is no in-built capability to save messages from Amazon SNS to Amazon S3.

However, this week AWS introduced Dead Letter Queues for Amazon SNS.

From [Amazon SNS Adds Support for Dead-Letter Queues (DLQ)](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/amazon-sns-adds-support-for-dead-letter-queues-dlq/):

> You can now set a **dead-letter queue (DLQ)** to an Amazon Simple Notification Service (SNS) subscription to capture undeliverable messages. Amazon SNS DLQs make your application more resilient and durable by storing messages **in case your subscription endpoint becomes unreachable.**
>
> Amazon SNS DLQs are standard Amazon SQS queues.

So, if Amazon SNS is unable to deliver a message, it can automatically send it to an Amazon SQS queue. You can later review/process those failed messages. For example, you could create an **AWS Lambda function** that is triggered when a message arrives in the Dead Letter Queue. The function could then store the message in Amazon S3.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your answer. What I want is to save all new messages that arrive at my SNS topic and persist it to an S3 file every  X minutes.